# Vector sum in C++ design strategy

Tags: c++, stl, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sum of elements in a `std::vector`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221812/sum-of-elements-in-a-stdvector)

I want to sum the items of a std::vector

For example

```
 std::vector<int > MYvec;
 /*some push backs*/

 int x=sum(MYVec); //it should give sum of all the items in the vector
```

How to write `sum` function?

I have tried this

```
 int sum(const std::vector<int> &Vec)
 {
    int result=0;
    for (int i=0;i<Vec.size();++i)
      result+=Vec[i];
    return result;
 }
```

However I don't like my approach

Answer (score 8):

Try to use [accumulate](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/algorithm/accumulate) from C++ standard library.
Something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

// Somewhere in code...
std::vector<int> MYvec;
/*some push backs*/

int sum = std::accumulate( MYvec.begin(), MYvec.end(), 0 );
```

Comment: Remember to `#include <algorithm>`.

Comment: `accumulate` comes from the `<numeric>` header.

Comment: See Prasoon's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221812/sum-of-elements-in-a-stdvector/3221813#3221813

Answer (score 2):

You should use `std::accumulate`.

```
int main() {
  std::vector<int> vec;
  // Fill your vector the way you like
  int sum = std::accumulate(vect.begin(), vect.end(), 0); // 0 is the base value
  std::cout << sum << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Isent there a std::accumulate function that does this?

Comment: Almost. `std::accumulate` uses `operator+`, not `operator+=`. But in any sane program, that should not make a difference, and with `int`s it definitely doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over all the items in the array and compute the sum, there is no easier way. I guess for cycle is the simplest

```
int sum = 0;
for(unsigned i = 0; i < Myvec.size(); i++){
   sum += MYvec[i];
}
```