# How calculate sum of values in std::vector<int>

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sum of elements in a `std::vector`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221812/sum-of-elements-in-a-stdvector)

I have `std::vector<int>` and I want to calculate the sum of all the values in that vector.
Is there any built in function or I need to write my custom code?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the STL algorithm [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), in the `numeric` header.

```
#include <numeric>

    // ...
    std::vector<int> v;
    // ...
    int sum = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3221813/52074 has an important warning about `std::accumulate`

Answer (score 11):

`accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);`

Look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/numeric/accumulate/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make your own custom code.

```
int sum = 0; for (int i = 0; i < myvector.size(); i++) sum += myvectory[i];
```

The answer is in the variable 'sum'.

Comment: This is not needed: std::accumulate does the same trick.