# How to get an average in C++?

Tags: c++

I have an assignment to read a file and output the average test scores.

It is pretty simple but I don't like how the average is done.

```
average = (test1 + test2 + test3 + test4 + test5) / 5.0;
```

Is there a way to just have it divide by the number of test scores? I couldn't find anything like this in the book or from google. Something like

```
average = (test + test + test + test) / ntests;
```

Comment: If the number of tests is not known until you read the input, you'd need a loop to do an average of *n* numbers.

Comment: Excellent question and an excellent observation. Hardcoding '5' is a) magic, and b) redundant.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner, please don't aid and abet people who are trying to circumvent a question ban.

Comment: Do you know how to count the scores as you go? Are you familiar with the idea of a running sum?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If you have the values in a vector or an array, just use [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) from `<numeric>`:

```
std::vector<double> vec;
// ... fill vec with values (do not use 0; use 0.0)
double average = std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0.0) / vec.size();
```

Comment: To elaborate on what @RiaD is saying: When you divide integers in C(++), it defaults to only using integer math - e.g. results of division are truncated, leaving you with no data after a decimal point. If your data set's values are large enough it isn't too big of a problem, but when dealing with smaller numbers, you don't want to loose that precision, it could result in a 0.75 turning into a flat 0.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a '0.' instead of just '0'? Because without the dot it will remain zero if you add up numbers in the range (-0.5, 0.5).

Comment: For sufficiently large values of `vec.size()` or large magnitude values in `vec`, consider using `std::transform` to divide each value by `vec.size()` before accumulating, as a more numerically stable solution

Answer (score 2):

Step 1. Via iteration (if you want to be done) or recursion (if you want to be brave) place all test scores into an array (if you want simplicity and speed) or a linked list (if you want flexibility but slow)

Step 2. Iterate through the array/list until you reach the end; adding the contents of each cell/node as you go. Keep a count of what cell/node you are currently at as you go as well.

Step 3. Take the sum from the first variable and divide it by the second variable that kept track of where you were. This will yield the mean.

Comment: Linked list is unlikely to be useful. It may make building the list slightly more efficent (but the amortized complexity is the same if you over-allocate, like most `vector`s do), but it makes summing and finding the length more complicated, and 1/3 is a pretty bad score.

Comment: This is all over my head by quite a bit. I pretty much just know cin cout and a few other things.

Comment: @Jordan Then this will provide a great opportunity to learn a little more than you know. Arrays or lists and iteration are fundamental to all computer languages -- the sooner you learn them, the better.

Answer (score 1):

Wondering, why no one mentioned `boost::accumulators`. It is not the shortest of the already posted solutions, but can be more easily extended for more general statistical values. Like standard deviation or higher moments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/stats.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/mean.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

double mean(const std::vector<double>& values) {
    namespace bo = boost::accumulators;

    if (values.empty()) return 0.;
    bo::accumulator_set<double, bo::stats<bo::tag::mean>> acc;
    acc=std::for_each(values.begin(), values.end(), acc);
    return bo::mean(acc);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> test = { 2.,6.,4.,7. };
    std::cout << "Mean:   " << mean(test) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Mean:   " << mean({}) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my generalization of getting the average of the elements of a container by specifying a lambda function to obtain each value and then add up:

```
template <typename ForwardIterator, typename F>
double inline averageOf (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, F function) {
    std::vector<typename std::result_of<F(typename ForwardIterator::value_type)>::type> values;
    while (first != last) {
        values.emplace_back (function(*first));
        ++first;
    }
    return static_cast<double>(std::accumulate (values.begin(), values.end(), 0)) / values.size();
}
```

The client code I tested it with goes like

```
const std::list<CharmedObserver*> devotees =
    charmer->getState<CharmerStateBase>(CHARMER)->getDevotees();
const int averageHitPointsOfDevotees = averageOf (devotees.begin(), devotees.end(),
    [](const CharmedObserver* x)->int {return x->getCharmedBeing()->getHitPoints();});
```

Answer (score 0):

C++11 gives nice solution:

```
constexpr auto countArguments() -> size_t
{
    return 0;
}

template<class T1, class ... Ti>
constexpr auto countArguments(T1, Ti ...xi) -> size_t
{
    return 1 + countArguments(xi...);
}

template<class T>
constexpr auto sumAruguments(T x) -> double
{
    return x;
}

template<class T1, class ... Ti>
constexpr auto sumAruguments(T1 x1, Ti ...xi) -> double // decltype(x1 + sumAruguments(xi...))
{
    return x1 + sumAruguments(xi...);
}

template<class...T>
constexpr auto avarage(T...xi) -> double
{
    return sumAruguments(xi...) / countArguments(xi...);
}
```

I was unable to write it so it auto-deduce return type.
When I tried I get weird result for `average(-2)`.

https://wandbox.org/permlink/brssPjggn64lBGVq

Comment: I would suggest that auto-deducing the return type is pointless. Even if you provide a list of `int` arguments, the average needs to be a floating point type, and on modern hardware should generally be a `double` anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You can also calculate average using variable number of arguments. The principle of this a function that an unknown number of arguments is stored in a stack and we can take them.

```
double average(int n, ...)          // where n - count of argument (number)
{  
    int *p = &n;                   // get pointer on list of number in stack
    p++;                           // get first number
    double *pp = (double *)p;      // transformation of the pointer type
    double sum = 0; 
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; pp++, i++ ) //looking all stack
       sum+=(*pp);                 // summarize
    return sum/n;              //return average
}
```

And you can using this function like:

```
double av1 = average( 5, 3.0, 1.5, 5.0, 1.0, 2.0 );
double av2 = average( 2, 3.0, 1.5 );
```

But the number of arguments must match with the n.

Comment: Be careful with this code. Its not guaranteed that p with work the way you expect, since you are relying upon implementation details.  At least on 64bit machines, were some arguments are passed through arguments, this code will not work.  To implement properly, look at va_start and co.  Also with c++11, there is varadic templates that can be used too.

Comment: @MJD was too kind. This is bad advice, and this code would never survive my code review. -1

Comment: It was about 10 year passed as I left this answer.
I have changed 4 companies, participated in many projects, wrote a lot of lines of code and much more have reviewed.
So, now with the proper level of responsibility, I can say that this answer is completely stupid.