# sum of non-integer elements in std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, functional-programming

I was reading following question: 
[How to sum up elements of a C++ vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221812/sum-of-elements-in-a-stdvector), and I wanted to use second method (`sum_of_elems =std::accumulate(vector.begin(),vector.end(),0);//#include <numeric>`).

However, I don't have `std::vector<int>`, but `std::vector<struct packet>`. The `packet` is defined as following:

```
struct packet {
    /// ...
    int length() const;
    ///
}
```

and I want sum of packet lengths.

This is what I tried:

```
std::vector<packet> packets;
...
std::accumulate(packets.begin(), packets.end(), 0, [](const packet& a, const packet& b){return a.length() + b.length();});
```

but it doesn't work. In C#, I'd write something like

```
packet[] p;
p.Select(x => p.length()).Sum();
```

Is it possible to do something like that in C++? I can write method for iterating through the vector and doing it on my own, but I prefer the functional approach where possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accumulating via a binary operation.  Your accumulated value starts with `0` (an `int`), so the left hand side of your binary operation has to be convertible-from `0` -- otherwise, how does it start adding?

Try this:

```
std::accumulate(
  packets.begin(),
  packets.end(),
  0,
  [](int a, const packet& b){
    return a + b.length();
  }
);
```

you can also do this via a simple loop:

```
int acc = 0;
for( const packet& p : packets ) {
  acc += packets.length();
}
```

Comment: The other solution are nice but the simple loop seems to explain everything without much effort on the part of the reader. +1

Answer (score 4):

I would note that the C# implementation is slightly different, in essence.

In C++ you are trying to add `int` and `packet` whilst in C# you first provide a transformation step from `packet` to `int` and then add `int`s.

The equivalent C++, without adaptation:

```
std::vector<size_t> lengths; // a length cannot be negative!

std::transform(packets.begin(),
               packets.end(),
               backward_inserter(lengths),
               [](packet const& p) { return p.length(); });

auto const sum = std::accumulate(lengths.begin(), lengths.end(), 0ul);
```

Of course, it is wasteful to store the intermediate lengths, however it does work out of the box.

But because we are cool, let us have look at `Boost.Range`, and more precisely:

- [`boost::accumulate`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/numeric/accumulate.html)
- [`boost::transformed`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html)

Which have a bit of coolness like Linq:

```
#include <boost/range/numeric.hpp> // accumulate
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>

size_t total_size(std::vector<packet> const& packets) {
    return boost::accumulate(
        packets | boost::transformed([](packet const& p) { return p.length(); }),
        0ul);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of the accumulate operation is the running total. In your case, this is an integer, not a packet, so your lambda should be

```
[](int a, const packet& b) {return a + b.length();}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your accumulate function. Its first parameter has to be of the type you're trying to accumulate (`int` in this case) and add a value on top of that.

Your lambda function should look like this: `[](int currTotal, const packet& b){return currTotal + b.length();}`

Answer (score 1):

Apart from lamba, you can change it to

```
std::accumulate(packets.begin(), packets.end(), 0, packet());
```

Where you can define functor as:

```
int operator() (int result, const packet& obj)
{
    return result+ obj.length();
}
```

Comment: That would work, but making `packet` double up as an accumulation functor is a bit weird - and a bad idea if it's expensive (or perhaps impossible) to copy. Why not use a specific functor class, like the lambda in the question?