# how to add the numbers inside an array together C++

Tags: c++, arrays

say I have an array that is an integer and stores five numbers, I want to add these numbers together and put them into a certain variable, how do I do this. if you have the answer to this then it would be greatly appreciated if you could respond. thanks.

Comment: `for(const auto& val:array) sum += val;` Remember to make `sum` a data type large enough to store the sum and also remember to initialize it to 0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum up elements of a C++ vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221812/how-to-sum-up-elements-of-a-c-vector)

Comment: See [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code to sum integers:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3NCsMgEITvPsVALwm10N9LYvIuYmwREi1mLYGQZ7dqDpnLwjczO@r7vahR2k@MJ2PVGAYN8dOKnO/ZQYybyWs59YwZS5iksVWNlSFppqFp9opIZg@JDuuN487x4HhyvLa2JHPV6znZ1x28nUclAzksDWRdWFYOnTss7TGgXCAIUax0CtN2GPeI1xS8zW@3GP8)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int res = 0;
    for (auto x: a)
        res += x;
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
15
```

Alternative way is to use [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY25DoMwDIb3PIWlLiCliF4LpLyLGywUKQcKSRfEs6chDNSLre8/LOf5KjXaKaWLslLHkUB8SQbnB3YS5ZbgCc0/s9GQV3JgTNkABpWtalgZ5FnC2HVHi8jiAAhvWG8c7hweHJ4cXltfnBiDA09L1ksIpYwmagxUYfOhaS/lgA3ZcT/auj8fSBcDCFHieRWWffqweArRW2h7tqX0Aw)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    auto res = std::accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0);
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```