# Why isn't my less-than operator processing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I just starting programming, just about a week ago, and I wanted to try and make a Blackjack game.

I wanted to run code using a `while` loop, while both hands are less than 21, run some code.

Simple enough.

But, for some reason, the less-than operator isn't working.

Here's the error message:

> C2676 binary '<': 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Can someone help me fix this?

Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> handone(0);
std::vector<int> handtwo(0);

int main() {
    while (handone < 21 && handtwo < 21) {
    }
}
```

Comment: you are comparing a vector with an integer. This obviously will not work. You need an index into the vector which will extract the integer within the vector, which can then be compared.

Comment: C++ doesn't just automatically understand that you want to sum the contents of vector. You need to tell it to do so. There are multiple ways that can be done. Googling "c++ sum contents of vector" will probably be educational.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification!

Comment: Here's some ways to sum a vector: [How to sum up elements of a C++ vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221812/how-to-sum-up-elements-of-a-c-vector), which you can then compare in your `while` condition.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is telling you that `std::vector` does not implement an `operator<` that takes an `int` as input.  Which is true, as it only implements an [`operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) to compare against another `vector` instead.

Assuming your `vector`s contain the values of individual cards, you will need to sum the values manually, such as with the standard [`std::accumulate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) algorithm, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> handone;
std::vector<int> handtwo;

int valueOfHand(const std::vector<int> &hand) {
    return std::accumulate(hand.begin(), hand.end(), 0);
}

int main() {
    while (valueOfHand(handone) < 21 && valueOfHand(handtwo) < 21) {
        ...
        handone.push_back(...);
        handtwo.push_back(...);
    }
}
```